# LUIS is no longer free?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Luis is no longer free ? 
I didn't open LUIS dashboard for 10-11 days. I'm seeing this now. They changed a lot of things there.

I must get azure key to get my LUIS app works ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [pricing details](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/language-understanding-intelligent-service-luis#pricingoptions), LUIS is not free. You are able to make 10K calls per month without charge, after which you are charged $0.75 per 1000 calls. Without more detail I am unsure of your second question. An azure key may be used to link LUIS to your bot.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify LUIS has the same model as before, the new portal just highlights this information in a different way that's a little more confusing (we're working on it).

- No Azure Account; free for 1000 requests/month using programmatic api key
- With Azure, free for 10,000 requests per month (F0 plan in Azure)
- With Azure, $.75/1000 calls

The thing that's new and confusing is the programmatic key with the low quota isn't connected to your app by default.  We're going to fix that shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me. I had to create LUIS app in Azure and then provide key to LUIS application on LUIS.ai. But in LUIS app on azure, you can select the pricing tier as free if 10k calls per month suffice your application usage or choose paid plan according to need.

A start-key is default available with each LUIS model which can be used upto 10k calls per month

Answer (score 0):

LUIS is free for Testing and Educational use. It is about 10000 conversations per month. However in production environment it has to be paid. 
The important this is you can access LUIS feature via Azure or can independently integrate it into your application. The method of costing will depend on that as well.